# How do I use JQuery to hide/display divs associated with an adjacent checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I'm just getting started with JQuery and am stumped.  I want a series of input checkboxes, that when checked, display/hide the adjacent textboxes.  I've gotten part of the logic but as you can probably tell, checking any one of the checkboxes, hides/displays ALL of the textboxes.  How can I make each checkbox only affect the contents of the div that is directly below it?  I don't want to write a separate function for each checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                            
$(document).ready(function() {

   $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        if ($(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
                $(".optionalinfo").show("fast");}
        else {      
                $(".optionalinfo").hide("fast");}
        });
});

 </script>   

 </head>                                                                 
 <body>                                                                  

<input id="chk1" type="checkbox">Hide/Show text1</input>
<div class="optionalinfo">
<input id="text1" type="text"></input>
</div>
<br>

<input id="chk2" type="checkbox">Hide/Show text2</input>                       
<div class="optionalinfo">
<input id="text2" type="text"></input>
</div>
<br>

<input id="chk3" type="checkbox">Hide/Show text3</input>                       
<div class="optionalinfo">
<input id="text3" type="text"></input>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the `div` adjacent to the checkbox:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(
    function()
        $(this).next('.optionalinfo').show();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4X6Dr/1/)

To make the checkbox a toggle:

```
$('input:checkbox').click(
    function() {
        $(this).next('.optionalinfo').toggle();
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/4X6Dr/)

Comment: I think yours is better than mine, because he should be using toggle.

Comment: @daybreaker, in this instance `toggle()` is merely a provided-method way of doing exactly the same thing as you propose in your own answer; but thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, it makes the code look much cleaner without all the if/else. It's a useful shortcut method.

Comment: That is so powerful.  I've got to grok this!

Answer (score 0):

use  ( jQuery v1.6)

```
$('input:checkbox').live ('click', function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $(this).next('div.optionalinfo').hide();
    }
    else {
          $(this).next('div.optionalinfo').show();
    }            
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Aztws/)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/next/

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                            
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        if ($(":checkbox").is(":checked")) {
            $(this).next('div.optionalinfo').show("fast");
        } else {      
            $(this).next('div.optionalinfo').hide("fast");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```